# My firebase cannot upload to the realtime database? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a firebase app from android kotlin. I've already set up and connected the firebase to my app. But I cannot upload the data to the database? When I click the button it just won't upload and its like skipping the code to upload it. Here's my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.buttonSave.setOnClickListener {
            saveData()
        }
    }

    private fun saveData() {
        val name = binding.etNama.text.toString().trim()
        val address = binding.etAlamat.text.toString().trim()

        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            binding.etNama.error = "Isi nama"
            return
        }
        if (address.isEmpty()) {
            binding.etAlamat.error = "Isi alamat"
            return
        }
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("mahasiswa")
        val mhsId = ref.push().key
        val mhs = Mahasiswa(mhsId,name,address)
        if (mhsId!=null){
            ref.child(mhsId).setValue(mhs).addOnCompleteListener {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Data berhasil ditambahkan",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My firebase database just stays null here
[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnYxE.png)

Here's the security rules:
[Security Rules Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwNzr.png)

Can anyone help me? Cause I can't figure this out.

Comment: Is `Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Data berhasil ditambahkan",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` showing something?

Comment: @AlexMamo not at all! The code is like skipping that code. I've checked it seems that the reason is it hasn't connected to the database. But I'm not sure why because in the firebase assistant it says that it has connected

Comment: Are you sure you have an internet connection on the device?

Comment: Yes my device is connected to the internet and have included the permission in my manifest already @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is how you update your data. When i create a node usually i do like in the code that i post.

Try the following code snippet. I think it can help you

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("mahasiswa").setValue(mhs)
            .addOnCompleteListener{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data save correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data PUSH ONLINE correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("Error", "error: " + it.message)
            }
```